# Codeingiter Session Resetting Automatically when load view page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using CI 3.1.0. On the login page, I set the user info for the session with `set_userdata`, after which I set the session redirect page to another controller, but the session data I set got destroyed.

```php
$this->session->set_userdata('admin_id',$data['admin_details']->id);
```

Comment: did you check if $data['admin_details']->id has a value? check with isset($_SESSION['admin_details'])

Comment: What version of php are you using? There is a known issue with codeigniter and PHP7 that concerns sessions. Try updating to the latest 3.x version

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your Codeigniter version to the latest one.
There is a session problem with the previous version of Codeigniter.
I recently had the same issue with my project.
After upgrading to a high version the problem got solved.